# How to separate classes and interfaces into separate files under the same namespace in Typescript

Tags: typescript, namespaces

This is a Typescript question about namespaces and file management. I have a number of interfaces and classes under a single namespace. I want to segment each class or interface into its own `.ts` file and then be able to aggregate the files so that I can just declare the namespace in some consuming code and then have accesses to the interfaces and classes within the namespace. For example, the first file, `icontact.ts`:

```js
export namespace mynamespace {
  export interface IContact {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }
}
```

Second file, `contact.ts`:

```js
import {IContact} from './icontact.ts';
export namespace mynamespace {
  export class Contact implements IContact {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string){
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName:
    } 
  }
}
```

I will really appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

namespaces in Typescript are a way to describe how modules are structured, but they don't generate any code that automatically does this for you.

What you will probably want to do, is to create a single file (perhaps `index.ts` in some directory), and from that file import everything you want in your 'namespace', and re-export.

Example of such an `index.ts` file:

```js
export { Foo } from './foo';
export { Bar } from './bar';
```

Now if something uses this module, they could reference it as such:

```js
import * as MyNamespace from './some/directory';

let foo: MyNamespace.Foo;
let bar: MyNamespace.Bar;
```

Comment: Tell me please, does the content of each file, `./foo.ts` and `.bar.ts` contain a namespace declaration? Of is the namespace implied by, `import * as MyNamespace from "./some/directory";`?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give attention to my question!

Comment: I mean, Or is the namespace implied by, `import * as MyNamespace from "./some/directory";`?

Comment: @reselbob there is no such thing as a real global namespace in javascript, unlike languages like Java or PHP. Typescript namespaces really just describe objects with names. So no, namespace is implied by how you import things.

Comment: Thanks. I just read the Typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-namespaces). It looks as if things are as you describe. Sadly, my style is to dedicate a file to each construct I make. Thus, my interest in namespaces for organizational purposes.

Comment: @reselbob you misunderstand. If you make an index file, this file can group a bunch of things together and it will appear to consumers as a 'namespace'. You just need something to re-export it.